# Voltage divider with potentiometer - Failsafe

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer, failure

I have a voltage divider circuit producing a reference voltage as follows:

[image]

Vref is the control voltage for a regulator, and Vmeasure the output voltage of the regulator, with Vref being regulated to 1.21V.

Now, if RV1 were to fail open or become disconnected (it is connected on a pin header), Vref would fail to 0V. However, **I need it to fail to Vmeasure**, because otherwise a lot of circuitry may get damaged.

The simple solution would of course be to swap R1 and RV1 and adjust the values, but this cannot be done on this board.

I have tried adding a PNP transistor to bypass RV1 in case the voltage goes too low, but this didn't work as anticipated when RV1 is disconnected:

[image]

This results in the voltage being too high when RV1 is connected and no change when connected.
The solution cannot be very complicated as it needs to be bodged onto the PCB.

Am I on the right track with this solution or what would you suggest?

Comment: I see no apparent solution with what you've shown us. Show us more of the circuit and what can be "damaged" and we may be able to help.

Comment: Use the simple solution, even if it means cutting traces and adding wires on the board.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Vref controls an output voltage that is adjustable and damageable component(s) is what a user connects. This is part of a power supply for a stepper motor driver.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ok, so given the situation you would recommend swapping R1 and RV1 yes?

Comment: @namezero yes...

Comment: Of course if the user shorts the pins or turns the pot down all the way you’ll still have an overvoltage situation with resistor and pot swapped.

Comment: Yes, turning the pot all the way downs would result in maximum voltage (that's acceptable). I would assume that nobody opens the case in operation, intentionally shorts out pins and expects a good outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Add a zener diode parallel with RV1 (with cathode connected to Vmeasure and anode connected to Vref). Choose a proper zener with a voltage according to the minimum allowable/safe value of Vref and the value of Vmeasure: Vzener = (Vmeasure - Vref_minimum).
In this way, Vref would never fall to zero, instead falls to Vmeasure - Vzener

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting a fixed resistor in parallel with the RV1 connections to set a maximum value of the output voltage.

This will likely require increasing RV1 and will involve some nonlinearity, but it might be good enough.

Comment: Mhh to fail to an acceptable level, the bypass resistor would have to be around 1k (to keep the voltage high enough with a 1/2 ratio). But that would preclude the resistance with RV1 connected from ever exceeding 1k, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, pots have a tolerance of 10-20% often, so maybe 1.1K or 1.2K 1% would be okay and you could use a 5K or 10K pot.

Comment: Ok, based on your last comment on the OP, I think there's a misunderstanding. Trimming the pot to 0 (or shorting the pins) is acceptable, the regulator will regulate the output voltage to the lowest level then. Which is what I want. In other words, if disconnected or failed, the pot should fail closed, not open.

Comment: With a 1k-ish resistor in parallel to the pot I could never achieve a Vmeasure/Vref ratio of > 2.